# How can I include the ObjectId in my newly serialized BsonDocument?

Tags: c#, mongodb

Given a snippet of json:

```
var _json = {MachineType: 'Sentient', Processor: 'Xalim', _id: '5094886393178c2970710e0c'}
```

How can call

```
var doc = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(_json);
```

In such a way that the resulting doc has the **id attached**? So far, I've tried the above and each new document gets saved with a new id, with an additional '_id' property dangling.

I know of this structure in the mongo shell, but how to do I do this when constructing the BsonDocument in c#?

```
_id: ObjectId('5094886393178c2970710e0c')
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops! This was my mistake. *My original posted json, when serialized into the BsonDocument, **DOES** update the db correctly with the matching `_id`*. Here's what I was actually trying to save:

```
{ System: { _id: '5094886393178c2970710e0c', MachineType: 'Sentient', Processor: 'Xalim' }}
```

This of course doesn't save back to the originating `_id` because it's not a property on the **parent** object (in this case, `system`). As soon as I moved my `_id` back to the parent, everything in the db updated as I expected.